# Rails 4 syntax to add parameter or lambda to includes conditions or pass params to relation scope

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have some models like

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  scope :recent ...
```

and like

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :post
  scope :written_by_user, ->(user_id) { where(:created_by => user_id) }
...
```

I'd like to load all the recent posts and lazily 'includes' any available Comments written by the user. The tricky part is I don't want to limit the posts to only posts with comments by the user, I want all of them, even if some of them have no valid comments.

Maybe something like...

```
Post.recent.includes(:comments).merge(Comment.written_by_user(current_user))
```

or

```
Post.recent.includes(:comments => :written_by_user(current_user))
```

Is there a nice Railsy way to do this or does it require sql and subqueries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't thing there is something like that in rails. `includes` works with the relations you defined on your models, that's where it gets all the details how to join tables.

if you need this for one specific user (say an admin) then you could define an extra relation with the `condition` section on it, something like `admin_comments` and then include them on models, but if you need a generic solution I doubt it's gonna work.

But then, you can preload the comments separately and then group them by the prost ids in a hash. that will give you pretty much the same result.

Comment: Thanks. Thats kind of the conclusion I came to. I'm working with a legacy system and was hoping to do this in the DB pull, but pulling both separately and grouping is probably more readable for the next guy.